# Итераторы в коллекциях Java

Tags: java

Почему при добавлении, изменении элементов в коллекции, не бросается исключение, когда инициализирован итератор? Но бросается только, когда удаляем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С точки зрения здравого смысла:

- Удаляя элементы, мы сокращаем размер коллекции, что могло бы привести к неопределенному поведению итератора (например, ни до ни после текущей позиции вдруг не оказалось бы элементов).
- Добавление/изменение не несет таких критических проблем.

Собственно, документация предусматривает использование ConcurrentModificationException для fail-fast итераторов. Т.е. тех, что не пытаются что-то решать за пользователя а "в любой непонятной ситуации" падают.

> For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances. Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do this are known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

Comment: ну пусть в цикле вызвали *next()*.При этом ни до , ни после не оказалось элементов.Это значит, что *next()* вернет null. Разве нельзя так определить поведение итератора? Или здесь важно , что бы пользователь был уверен, что в цикле *while(iterator.hasNext())* не будет вызвано исключений?

Comment: Можно, но еще раз повторяю, стратегия итератора в данном случае: fail-fast, падать сразу. Java в отличие от другого популярного языка с двумя плюсами заботится, чтобы программист не убился и не поранился )

Comment: Это как автоматическая коробка передач. Вот только гонщики используют механику...

Comment: Никто не препятствует написать свою коробку передач )

Comment: Блин, я только щас прочитал, что исключение выбросится и при добавлении! Это ,видимо нововведение JavaSE7